# Java ArrayIndexOutofBounds error when executing jar

Tags: java, jar, indexoutofboundsexception, executable-jar

I am trying to execute my jar file but I keep getting an `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`.
This is the only error that appears on the screen when I run the command `java -jar MyFile.jar`

I have looked at other questions with similar problems, but nothing seems to work. I didn't write this code so I don't actually know what the code is completely doing. I am also running this after building a dockerfile and bringing it down locally and running it in a script.

I unzipped the jar file to see what the main class is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main--Class: com.example.mypackage.Main.class
```

This was originally executed in a batch file using:

```
java -cp MyFile.jar com.example.mypackage.Main 'new location in directory'
```

Comment: You should give us the entire stack trace for this error. And then see where is the error and analyze it with the source code or a decompiler

Comment: Indeed you should give us more information, especially the main function content. However, It's weird to have a Main-Class named "java"

Comment: I'm sorry for not being more clear. This error was the only thing that appeared, so I am not sure where the error is coming from. I also did not write the main function, so I do not have the content of it. However, I do have the commands of how it was executed from a batch file (I am trying to re-write it to execute in a shell script ) which I added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If no arguments are provided, the args argument to main is a zero length array. Trying to access element zero will give this error